# MySQL: select parent when child matches condition

Tags: mysql, join, parent, subquery

i have the following situation.

Table "parent" has parent objects:

```
+-----+-------------------+
| UID | some_parent_stuff |
+-----+-------------------+
|  1  | value01           |
+-----+-------------------+
|  2  | value02           |
|     |                   |
```

The table child has objects with a reference column to parents and a status:

```
+-----+-------------+------------+
| UID | parent_uid  | status_uid |
+-----+-------------+------------+
|  1  | 2           | 1          |
+-----+-------------+------------+
|  2  | 2           | 5          |
+-----+-------------+------------+
|  3  | 1           | 2          |
|     |             |            |
```

Now i'd like to select all parents, from which the child with the highest UID has a status_uid in a list (i.e. IN(1,5)).

I have something like this:

```
SELECT P.uid FROM parent P
INNER JOIN child C ON C.parent_uid = P.uid AND C.status_uid IN(1)
GROUP BY P.uid;
```

This returns parent with UID 2 too. But it has a child with a higher UID, which has a status not in the IN-Clause. So i dont want to select it.

I hope you understand my question, my english isn't the best... Thx for ideas and with best regards

Kjuuze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you need is a query within your query (PreQuery in my sample).  The inner query gets on a per parent id basis, the maximum child-level uid regardless of the qualifying status ID.  Since this is grouped by parent, it will return two records per your example data.

```
Child Table
UID   Parent   Status
2     2        5
3     1        2
```

Now, you can join to both the parent table and the child table from this prequery on the respective IDs, and at the second CHILD-LEVEL join, add your criteria for the status in (1,5)

```
SELECT
      p.uid, 
      p.some_parent_stuff,
      c2.uid,
      c2.status_uid
   from 
      ( select c.parent_uid,
               MAX( c.uid ) as ChildUID
            from
               child c
            group by 
               c.parent_uid ) PreQuery
      JOIN Parent p
         ON PreQuery.parent_uid = p.uid
      JOIN Child c2
         ON PreQuery.ChildUID = c2.uid
        AND c2.status_id in ( 1, 5 )
```

This will return only the 1 record for Child ID 2, Parent 2, Status 5.  Since the Child ID of 3 has a status of 2, it will NOT be returned in final result set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This pushes me in the right direction. But I simplified it a little too much... What to do if the child table has a column "crdate" (timestamp), which has to be the highest value. I can't compare the value from MAX(crdate), because under some circumstances it is not unique.

Comment: @Kjuuze, then all you have to do is change the max( c.uid ) to the max( c.crdate ), then the JOIN would be for the PreQuery max date column to the same max date too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.uid 
FROM parent P
INNER JOIN child C ON C.parent_uid = P.uid AND C.status_uid IN(1)
WHERE C.status_uid = (
SELECT MAX(status_uid) 
FROM child)
GROUP BY P.uid;
```

If I understood what you are asking this should work, however this is not tested, you can also   review mysql sub queries[mysql](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) here